# short term memory and long term memory and its affect on expertise and novices

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Please help me get this concepts..
Its known that an expert in math may think too long whenever there is a new problem
trying to match what he have learned, while a novice may plug numbers with out thinking.

I also, understand that some expert such computer programmers make more mistakes in projects than novice
but I don't know why or how to relate this to short or long term memory.

so please help answering the below questions. (then I will be able to understand the above one)

Using short-term memory's 
how novices can damage their expertise.

Using patterns in long-term memory
describe how experts:

Acquire expertise;
Apply that expertise to solve harder problems, faster.

Comment: That's a psychology question, not a programming problem.

Comment: sorry, this is regarding to AI (sorry the first two line was just my reflection on actual case)

Comment: I don't see anything related to AI here.